# propriedade order não funciona

Tags: html, css

Boas

eu criei uma pagina para pc e queria que a ordem que mostra algumas coisas sejam alteradas com a propriedade order de css, mas eu ns o que se passa que não está a trocar a ordem dos objetos, alguem pode dar uma olhada?

Codigo:

```css
.conti p {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        width: 94%;
        line-height: 16px;
        font-size: 12px;
        float: none;
    }
    .conti h1 {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100vw;
        height: auto;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .texto-conti {
        order: 1;
    }
    .conti-img {
        order: 2;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .conti {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="conti">
            <div class="conti-img"></div>
            <div class="texto-conti">
                <h1>Rio Lis</h1>
                <p>O Rio Lis é um rio português que nasce junto da povoação das Fontes, dois quilómetros e meio a Sul da
                    freguesia de Cortes, a que pertence, ao distrito e concelho da cidade de Leiria. Esta cidade é
                    banhada
                    pelas suas águas onde se juntam às do Rio Lena.</p>
                <p>A poluição no rio lis que antes era usado para pescar, ensinar crianças a nadar e parcialmente como
                    água
                    potável, está a afetar o ambiente bem como os animais em que estão incluídos peixes, patos e gansos
                    entre outros.</p>
                <p>Devido a esta mesma poluição hoje em dia já não é seguro nadar nestas águas nem consumir os peixes
                    que
                    nelas tem o seu habitat natural.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

se repararem eu tenho a primeira div com order 2 e a segunda div com order 1 pois o objetivo e que quando passe para telemovel a imagem passe para baixo dos textos mas eu não sei se falta alguma coisa para a propriedade funcionar, se poderem dar uma olhada sff.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara não adianta apenas  colocar `order` no elemento e esperar que ele mude de posição,  o `order` só funciona  nos elementos filhos diretos de um container com `display:flex` ou `display:grid`.

Esses tipos de display, assim como o `display:table`, mudam o escopo dos elementos filhos diretos, e esses elementos passam a aceitar algumas propriedades css intrínsecas do pai. Todo filho de um `display:grid` é um `grid-cell`, todo filho de um `flex` é um `flex-iten` e todo filho de uma `table` é um `table-cell`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então primeiro declare `display:flex` ou `display:grid` no container de pai,  e depois defina o `order` dos filhos.

Abaixo eu usei `display:grid` pq o *stack* dele é **um elemento abaixo do outro**, já o stack do `flex` não ficaria legal pq **um elemento ficaria ao lado do outro.**

```css
.conti p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 94%;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: none;
}
.conti h1 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.texto-conti {
    order: 1;
}
.conti-img {
    order: 2;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 200px;
}
.conti {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="conti">
  <div class="conti-img">
    <img src="https://www.placecage.com/100/100">
    imagem com order 2, vai vir abaixo do texto que é order 1
  </div>
  <div class="texto-conti">
      <h1>Rio Lis</h1>
      <p>O Rio Lis é um rio português que nasce junto da povoação das Fontes, dois quilómetros e meio a Sul da
          freguesia de Cortes, a que pertence, ao distrito e concelho da cidade de Leiria. Esta cidade é
          banhada
          pelas suas águas onde se juntam às do Rio Lena.</p>
      <p>A poluição no rio lis que antes era usado para pescar, ensinar crianças a nadar e parcialmente como
          água
          potável, está a afetar o ambiente bem como os animais em que estão incluídos peixes, patos e gansos
          entre outros.</p>
      <p>Devido a esta mesma poluição hoje em dia já não é seguro nadar nestas águas nem consumir os peixes
          que
          nelas tem o seu habitat natural.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou! E percebi bem o que quis dizer! Obrigado!

Comment: @DavidMv legal que bom que fez sentido para vc, tem display que muda os elementos que estão dentro de outro elemento, como é o caso do flex, e tem display que muda o elemento com relação aos outros elementos que estão ao lado como é o caso do inline-block. tmj

Answer (score 2):

A propriedade `order` funcionaria em elementos flexbox. A div `.conti` que possui as duas divs com `order` poderia ter a propriedade `display: flex` e no seu caso, outra propriedade, `flex-direction: column;`, para orientar o conteúdo em forma de coluna:

```css
.conti p {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        width: 94%;
        line-height: 16px;
        font-size: 12px;
        float: none;
    }
    .conti h1 {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100vw;
        height: auto;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .texto-conti {
        order: 1;
    }
    .conti-img {
        order: 2;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .conti {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
```

```html
<div class="conti">
   <div class="conti-img">conti-img</div>
   <div class="texto-conti">
       <h1>Rio Lis</h1>
       <p>O Rio Lis é um rio português que nasce junto da povoação das Fontes, dois quilómetros e meio a Sul da
           freguesia de Cortes, a que pertence, ao distrito e concelho da cidade de Leiria. Esta cidade é
           banhada
           pelas suas águas onde se juntam às do Rio Lena.</p>
       <p>A poluição no rio lis que antes era usado para pescar, ensinar crianças a nadar e parcialmente como
           água
           potável, está a afetar o ambiente bem como os animais em que estão incluídos peixes, patos e gansos
           entre outros.</p>
       <p>Devido a esta mesma poluição hoje em dia já não é seguro nadar nestas águas nem consumir os peixes
           que
           nelas tem o seu habitat natural.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```